# Generate context free grammar for the following language:

Tags: grammar

The set of string from the alphabet {j,k} where the string can be reversed and then all j's changed to k's and all k's changed to j's.

For example "jjkk" would be in the language because when you reverse it: "kkjj" and when you flip all of the characters to the other character: "jjkk"

"kjk" would not be in the language because when you reverse it: "kjk" (the same) and flipping the characters yields "jkj" which is not the same as the starting string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string can't be an odd length because then the middle character can't be flipped. Every *ith* character from the left that is a `j` must have a corresponding `k` *i* characters from the right. The same holds for `k`s on the left and `j`s on the right. So:

```
S ::= ε | jSk | kSj
```